# Nested Tables in Bootstrap Not Lining Up Correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a series of nested tables in bootstrap but the sub-tables in each category aren't lined up correctly. The code is too long to post here but I have it in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c310uxxf/1

Here is a snippet of the code:

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Loan Status</th>
            <th>Number of Loans</th>
            <th>Total Loan Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tr class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Registered">
        <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Registered</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>$800,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan='2' class="accordion-body collapse" id="Registered">
            <table id="example" class="table table-striped responsive-utilities jambo_table">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="headings">
                        <th>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="tableflat">
                        </th>
                        <th>Invoice </th>
                        <th>Invoice Date </th>
                        <th>Order </th>
                        <th>Bill to Name </th>
                        <th>Status </th>
                        <th>Amount </th>
                        <th class=" no-link last">
                            <span class="nobr">Action</span>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="even pointer">
                        <td class="a-center ">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="tableflat">
                        </td>
                        <td class=" ">121000040</td>
                        <td class=" ">May 23, 2014 11:47:56 PM </td>
                        <td class=" ">
                            121000210 <i class="success fa fa-long-arrow-up"></i>
                        </td>
                        <td class=" ">John Blank L</td>
                        <td class=" ">Paid</td>
                        <td class="a-right a-right ">$7.45</td>
                        <td class=" last">
                            <a href="#">View</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="odd pointer">
                        <td class="a-center ">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="tableflat">
                        </td>
                        <td class=" ">121000037</td>
                        <td class=" ">May 24, 2014 10:52:44 PM</td>
                        <td class=" ">121000204</td>
                        <td class=" ">Mike Smith</td>
                        <td class=" ">Paid</td>
                        <td class="a-right a-right ">$333.21</td>
                        <td class=" last">
                            <a href="#">View</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

It actually looks a little better in the fiddle then with all the themes and customaizations but it still doesn't line up right. I'm trying to get the subtables (the ones under Registered, Submitted, & Locked) to span the full width of the tables they are nested under. Its probably something simple but I just can't figure it out.

Any help would be great.

Comment: in your fiddle in html..line 311, make sure you have structured `<tbody>` and `<table>` properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you want subtables (the ones under Registered, Submitted, & Locked) to span the full width of the tables they are nested under.

Problem is that subtable are defined in one td of tr but its sibling tr have three columns so for the tr which have this subtable you will have to combine one column of three columns i.e colspan="3"

Please click on [JS Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/2crd09ae/) to see the proper width.

```
<body class="nav-md">
<div class="container body">

    <div class="main_container">

         <div class="right_col" role="main">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="x_panel">


                    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Loan Status</th>
                                <th>Number of Loans</th>
                                <th>Total Loan Amount</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tr class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Registered">
                            <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Registered</td>
                            <td>5</td>
                            <td>$800,000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan='2' class="accordion-body collapse" id="Registered">
                                <table id="example" class="table table-striped responsive-utilities jambo_table">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr class="headings">
                                            <th>
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="tableflat">
                                            </th>
                                            <th>Invoice </th>
                                            <th>Invoice Date </th>
                                            <th>Order </th>
                                            <th>Bill to Name </th>
                                            <th>Status </th>
                                            <th>Amount </th>
                                            <th class=" no-link last">
                                                <span class="nobr">Action</span>
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr class="even pointer">
                                            <td class="a-center ">
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="tableflat">
                                            </td>
                                            <td class=" ">121000040</td>
                                            <td class=" ">May 27, 2014 11:47:56 PM </td>
                                            <td class=" ">121000210</td>
                                            <td class=" ">John Blank L</td>
                                            <td class=" ">Paid</td>
                                            <td class="a-right a-right ">$7.45</td>
                                            <td class=" last">
                                                <a href="#">View</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="odd pointer">
                                            <td class="a-center ">
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="tableflat">
                                            </td>
                                            <td class=" ">121000039</td>
                                            <td class=" ">May 28, 2014 11:30:12 PM</td>
                                            <td class=" ">121000208</td>
                                            <td class=" ">John Blank L</td>
                                            <td class=" ">Paid</td>
                                            <td class="a-right a-right ">$741.20</td>
                                            <td class=" last">
                                                <a href="#">View</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Submitted">
                                <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Submitted</td>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>$400,000</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="accordion-body collapse" colspan="3" id="Submitted">
                                    <table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
                                        <thead>
                                        <th>Loan #</th>
                                        <th>Borrower</th>
                                        <th>Program</th>
                                        <th>Loan Amount</th>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>123</td>
                                                <td>John Smith</td>
                                                <td>Conventional</td>
                                                <td>$100,000</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>321</td>
                                                <td>Bob Sanders</td>
                                                <td>FHA</td>
                                                <td>$300,000</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Locked">
                                <td><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Locked</td>
                                <td>5</td>
                                <td>$800,000</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="accordion-body collapse" colspan="3" id="Locked">
                                    <table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
                                        <thead>
                                        <th>Loan #</th>
                                        <th>Borrower</th>
                                        <th>Program</th>
                                        <th>Loan Amount</th>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>5</td>
                                                <td>John Doe</td>
                                                <td>Conventional</td>
                                                <td>$100,000</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>6</td>
                                                <td>Jane Doe</td>
                                                <td>FHA</td>
                                                <td>$300,000</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>


                            </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Hope this helps you.